# PyQt QString masks special characters and does not display correctly

Tags: python, pyqt, qstring

I cannot get PyQt to display a string with special characters correctly. From a drag and drop action I end up with filenames as QString that may contain a blank or one of the ugly German Umlaute

For simplicity let's consider this is the filename I'd like to handle: `'abc defä.ghi'`, the resulting QString I get is `'abc%20.def%C3%A4.ghi'`. I now just want to print the original string:

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import QString, QTextCodec, QTextDecoder
s = QString('abc%20.def%C3%A4.ghi')
print s, unicode(s), s.toUtf8()
```

Nothing seems to work and I'm afraid I'm missing the obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure where you're getting the data from, but it's obviously not UTF-8 encoded. It's percent-encoded - so from the internet, somehow?

Anyway, it should be decoded like this in python2:

```
>>> b = QtCore.QByteArray.fromPercentEncoding('abc%20.def%C3%A4.ghi')
>>> b.data()
'abc .def\xc3\xa4.ghi'
>>> s = b.data().decode('utf8')
>>> print s
abc .defä.ghi
```

Comment: Actually it is not from the internet but a drag'n'drop result from dragging files from Windows Explorer to a QListWidget. I missed the fromPercentEncoding method of QByteArray completely. I was a bit confused by the `%` sign but obviously did not think this completely through